# Prove that for any integer $n$, if $b^2$ divides $n$, then $b$ divides $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for any integer $n$, if $b^2$ divides $n$, then $b$ divides $n$.

Trying to figure out this proof. The proof I'm looking at is written as
$n$ = any integer, if $25|n \implies 5|n$. 
I've been trying to figure this for days and have been running around in circles. Would appreciate a general proof for this.

$n$ = any integer, if $(b^2)|n \implies b|n$.

Comment: Hint: $b~\mid~ b^2$.

Comment: You could also try breaking $n,b$ down into their prime factorizations.

Comment: Yes, but that's too much work. Use my hint, and a property of $\mid$.

Comment: $$b^2\mid n\implies n=b^2k=bbk=b\ell\implies b\mid n.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the definition: If $a \mid b \Rightarrow$ there is an integer $k$ such that $b=ak$.

So if $b^2 \mid n \Rightarrow$ there is an integer $k$ such that $n=b^2k= bbk$. Now the product of two integers is also an integer, setting $c = bk$, what can you conclude?

Comment: This helped so much! Thank you

Comment: @ShanSolo no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since an answer has been given ...

The $\mid$ relation is transitive; if $x \mid y$ and $y\mid z$, then $x\mid z$. Let $x=b$, $y=b^2$, and $z=n$. Done.